# Graphene GraphQL on return return records where calculated field is greater than zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphql, graphene-python

I have a GrpahQL endpoint that returns all the Magic the Gathering cards for a particular MtG set. I have created a field that returns a list of calculated fields which is the delta is card price between two days. I would like to filter all the cards where the delta percentage is greater than 0.

so something along the lines of `return magic_sets_cards_pricing.objects.filter(MagicSetsGainsPricing.delta_percent>0)`

**Code:**

```py
class MagicSetsGainsPricing(graphene.ObjectType):
    value = graphene.String()
    delta_percent = graphene.String()
    delta_value = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        model = magic_sets_cards_pricing

    def resolve_gains(self, info, days=None, **kwargs):
        us = auth_user_settings.objects.values('region', 'currency').get()
        if us['region'] == 'Europe':
            region_nf = 'eur'
            match us['currency']:
                case 'Pound':
                    symbol = '£'
                    rate = currency_exchanges.objects.filter(c_from='EUR').filter(c_to='GBP').values('rate').get()['rate']
                case 'Dollar':
                    symbol = '$'
                    rate = currency_exchanges.objects.filter(c_from='EUR').filter(c_to='USD').values('rate').get()['rate']
                case _:
                    symbol = '€'
                    rate = 1
        else:
            region_nf = 'usd'
            match us['currency']:
                case 'Pound':
                    symbol = '£'
                    rate = currency_exchanges.objects.filter(c_from='USD').filter(c_to='GBP').values('rate').get()['rate']
                case 'Euro':
                    symbol = '€'
                    rate = currency_exchanges.objects.filter(c_from='USD').filter(c_to='EUR').values('rate').get()['rate']
                case _:
                    symbol = '$'
                    rate = 1

        price_today = magic_sets_cards_pricing.objects.filter(card_id=self).values('date', region_nf).order_by('-date')[0:1][0][region_nf] or 0
        calc_price_today = round((price_today * rate), 2)

        price_previous = magic_sets_cards_pricing.objects.filter(card_id=self).values('date', region_nf).order_by('-date')[days:days+1][0][region_nf] or 0
        calc_price_previous = round((price_previous * rate), 2)

        calc_delta_value = str(calc_price_today - calc_price_previous)
        calc_delta_percent = str(round(((calc_price_today - calc_price_previous)  / (calc_price_previous or 1)) * 100, 2))

        return MagicSetsGainsPricing(
            value=symbol + str(calc_price_today),
            delta_value=symbol + calc_delta_value,
            delta_percent=calc_delta_percent + '%',
        )


class MagicSetsGains(DjangoObjectType):
    pricing = graphene.Field(MagicSetsGainsPricing, days=graphene.Int(), resolver=MagicSetsGainsPricing.resolve_gains)

    class Meta:
        model = magic_sets_cards

    def resolve_pricing(self, info, **kwargs):
        return magic_sets_cards_pricing.objects.filter(card_id=self)


class MagicSetsGainsQuery(ObjectType):
    magic_sets_gains = graphene.List(MagicSetsGains, code=graphene.String())

    def resolve_magic_sets_gains(self, info, code=None, **kwargs):
        sql_number_to_int = "CAST((REGEXP_MATCH(number, '\d+'))[1] as INTEGER)"
        excluded_sides = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
        return magic_sets_cards.objects.filter(set_id__code=code).exclude(side__in=excluded_sides).extra(select={'int': sql_number_to_int}).order_by('int', 'number').all()
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "magicSetsGains": [
      {
        "number": "1",
        "name": "Adeline, Resplendent Cathar",
        "pricing": {
          "value": "£2.23",
          "deltaValue": "£0.52",
          "deltaPercent": "30.41%"
        }
      },
      {
        "number": "2",
        "name": "Ambitious Farmhand // Seasoned Cathar",
        "pricing": {
          "value": "£0.07",
          "deltaValue": "£-0.04",
          "deltaPercent": "-36.36%"
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `filter` function, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822280/python-api-filter-result-by-element/70822598#70822598)

Comment: Sorry cant see how that answer is related to GraphQL and Graphene

Comment: What I meant was that you could just filter the response.

Answer (score 0):

So you cant use the `model.objects.filter()` because that filters the objects on the database level, and the database doesn't know about the "delta_percent" field that you've calculated at the schema level. However you can filter it in python using the `filter` function.

What I would suggest you do is this. Firstly, the code inside `resolve_gains` needs to move outside of the schema into a utility file and you can name it something like `get_pricing_for_card(card, days=None)` that returns a dict with `{"value": blah, "delta_percent": blah, "delta_price": blah}`.

Then your `resolve_gains` becomes:

```py
def resolve_gains(self, info, days=None, **kwargs):
    pricing = get_pricing_for_card(self, days)
    return MagicSetsGainsPricing(**pricing)
```

Then `MagicSetsGainsQuery` becomes this:

```py
class MagicSetsGainsQuery(ObjectType):
    magic_sets_gains = graphene.List(MagicSetsGains, code=graphene.String())

    def resolve_magic_sets_gains(self, info, code=None, **kwargs):
        sql_number_to_int = "CAST((REGEXP_MATCH(number, '\d+'))[1] as INTEGER)"
        excluded_sides = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
        cards_to_return = magic_sets_cards.objects.filter(set_id__code=code).exclude(side__in=excluded_sides).extra(select={'int': sql_number_to_int}).order_by('int', 'number').all()
        return filter(lambda card: get_pricing_for_card(card)["delta_percent"] > 0, cards_to_return)
```

Alternatively you can replace the return line with:

```py
return [card for card in cards_to_return if get_pricing_for_card(card)["delta_percent"] > 0]
```

I know this isn't great because essentially you end up running `get_pricing_for_card` twice. This is a little annoying thing about the graphene schema where you can't really pass around values calculated in the resolve function. The larger refactor to this would be that you save the pricing in the pricing table with the delta percent field and so forth, when you create a card. then you can do `pricing.objects.filter(delta_percent__gte=0)`

Comment: There is a mistake in this. `get_price_for_card` actually should be a `get_price_for_pricing`. and whenever you have a card you need the get the pricing for it first and then pass it into `get_price_for_pricing(pricing)`. my bad